# Getting error in installing any plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Update failed: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.

I have changed the directory permission to 777 and added the code- define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . '/../temp/');
but the same error is coming.